# how to get attribute data using python beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm, web-crawler

Hi am trying to use python beautiful-soup web crawler to get data from imdb i have followed the documentation online am able to retrieve all the data using this code

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1405406/episodes?season=1&ref_=tt_eps_sn_1'
response = get(url)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)

movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'image')
print(movie_containers)
```

with the above code am able to retrieve a list of all the data in the div class tagged as image just as show below

```
<div class="image">
<a href="/title/tt1486497/" itemprop="url" title="Pilot"> <div class="hover-over-image zero-z-index" data-const="tt1486497">
<img alt="Pilot" class="zero-z-index" height="126" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTExMDIwNTUyNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzU5MDg1Mg@@._V1_UX224_CR0,0,224,126_AL_.jpg" width="224"/>
<div>S1, Ep1</div>
</div>
</a> </div>
<div class="image">
<a href="/title/tt1485650/" itemprop="url" title="The Night of the Comet"> <div class="hover-over-image zero-z-index" data-const="tt1485650">
<img alt="The Night of the Comet" class="zero-z-index" height="126" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjIyNDczNDYzNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDk1MDQ4Mg@@._V1_UX224_CR0,0,224,126_AL_.jpg" width="224"/>
<div>S1, Ep2</div>
</div>
</a> </div>
```

but am trying to get the value of the attributes **data-const** as gotten from the result i want to display just the values of the **data-const** attribute instead of the whole html result Expected Result : **tt1486497, tt1485650**

Answer (score 0):

Instead use the class name that `div` is using.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="image">
<a href="/title/tt1486497/" itemprop="url" title="Pilot"> <div class="hover-over-image zero-z-index" data-const="tt1486497">
<img alt="Pilot" class="zero-z-index" height="126" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTExMDIwNTUyNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzU5MDg1Mg@@._V1_UX224_CR0,0,224,126_AL_.jpg" width="224"/>
<div>S1, Ep1</div>
</div>
</a> </div>
<div class="image">
<a href="/title/tt1485650/" itemprop="url" title="The Night of the Comet"> <div class="hover-over-image zero-z-index" data-const="tt1485650">
<img alt="The Night of the Comet" class="zero-z-index" height="126" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjIyNDczNDYzNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDk1MDQ4Mg@@._V1_UX224_CR0,0,224,126_AL_.jpg" width="224"/>
<div>S1, Ep2</div>
</div>
</a> </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for div in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"hover-over-image zero-z-index"}):
    print(div["data-const"])
```

Output:

```
tt1486497
tt1485650
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

```
for dc in movie_containers.select('div.hover-over-image'):
    print(dc['data-const'])
```

output:

```
tt1486497
tt1485650
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [**requests-html**](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/). It's more intuitive than just using beautiful soup.

Example:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1405406/episodes?season=1&ref_=tt_eps_sn_1'
session = HTMLSession()

response = session.get(url)
html = response.html

imageContainers = html.find_all("div.image")

dataConsts = list(map(lambda x: x.find("a", first=True).attrs["data-const"], imageContainers))
```

This should exactly do what you need, but I couldn't test it

Good luck!